# Proof verification for $fgh=1_A\dots\implies f,g,h$ are all bijections. - Cohn - Classic Algebra Page 15

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Is the proof below correct? Thank you for your time!

**Notation:** $xfgh\equiv h(g(f(x)))= (h \circ g \circ f)(x)$

**Theorem:** If $f:A\to B, g:B\to C, h:C\to A$ are three mappings such that $fgh=1_A$, $ghf=1_B$ and $hfg=1_C$ then each of $f,g,h$ are all bijections.

**Proof:**

---

**Observation A:** We can see that $f^{-1}=(gh)$, $g^{-1}=(hf)$,$h^{-1}=(fg)$

---

**Claim 1:** $fgh$ is injective

**Proof:** 
 $afgh=bfgh=aff^{-1}=bff^{-1}=a=b$

Hence $fgh$ is injective

**Observation B:** Injectivity of $ghf$ and $hfg$ follows similarly

---

**Claim 2:** $f$ is injective

**Proof:** Since $fgh$ is injective, $f$ is necessarily injective

---

**Claim 3:** $ghf$ is surjective.

**Proof:** $(\forall b\in A)(\exists b\in C)|bghf=b)$

Since $ghf=1_B,bghf=b$, thus $ghf$ is clearly surjective.

---

**Claim 4:** $ghf$ surjective $\implies f$ is surjective.

**Proof:** We have $ghf$ surjective, meaning $(\forall b\in B)(\exists b\in B)|(bghf=b)$

Hence $bg=c$ gives us $(\forall b\in B)(\exists b\in B)|((ch)f=b)$

and $ch=a$ gives us $(\forall b\in B)(\exists b\in B)|(af=b)$
Which is the definition of $f$ being surjective.

---

**Observation C:** $f$ is a bijection and $g$ and $h$ can be proven as above. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but can probably be shortened: $fgh=1_A$ implies:

- $h$ is surjective: $\forall x\in A$, $h(g(f(x)))=x$;
- $f$ is injective: if $x\neq y\in A$, then $h(g(f(x))=x\neq y=h(g(f(y))$ implying $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

Similarly, $ghf=1_B$ implies that $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective and $hfg=1_C$ implies that $g$ is surjective and $h$ is injective. Putting everything together, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: Genius! Thank you!